# Language browser detection and action rewrite

Tags: php, .htaccess, locale

Till now I have been using `htaccess` to rewrite `?action` only with this code:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^action=([^&\s]+)$
RewriteRule ^(?:index\.php|)$ /%1? [R=301,L]


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^\s\/]+)/?$ index.php?action=$1&r [L,QSA]
```

Now I dived into a multi language website and I would like to detect user´s browser language and based on this information redirect him to his language version

And to rewrite this:

```
index.php?lang=en&action=subpage
```

into

```
en/subpage
```

Comment: FYI `index.php?lang=en?action=subpage` is not valid and should be `index.php?lang=en&action=subpage`

Comment: Have a query parameter as `?lang=en` is different from `detect user´s browser language`. You have to decide which route you want to take.

Comment: @anubhava ok then as query parametr ?lang=en :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have your rules like this in site root .htaccess:

```sh
RewriteEngine On

# external redirect from actual URL to pretty one
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /(?:index\.php)?\?lang=([^\s&]+)&action=([^\s&]+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2? [R=301,L,NE]

# add default language prefix
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^([a-z]{2})- [NC]
RewriteRule ^(?![a-z]{2}/)[^/]*/?$ /%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]

# internal forward from pretty URL to actual one
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/([\w-]+)/?$ index.php?lang=$1&action=$2 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: Thank you, this works and I can work with this, so really thanks. 
One more thing, when someones enter the website, is it possible to make default url with language?

So when I enter stackoverflow.com it will redirect to stackoverflow.com/en

Comment: sure check my updated answer